# R %in% operator for RefClass objects

Tags: r, match

I've the following problem. I know how to do a workaround for this but its more of a esthetic thing:

```
A <- setRefClass("A", fields = list(a = "character"))

A$methods(
  equal = function(obj){
    a == obj$a
  }
)

setMethod("==",signature = c("A","A"), function(e1,e2){e1$equal(e2)})

a1 <- A(a="xxx")
a2 <- A(a="yyy")
a3 <- A(a="xxx")

a1 == a2 # FALSE
a1 == a3 # TRUE

A1 <- sapply(c("a","b","c","d"),function(x)A(a=x))
A2 <- sapply(c("c","d","e"),function(x)A(a=x))

A1 
A2   

A2 %in% A1 # TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE but I would expect FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

A1 %in% A2 # TRUE TRUE TRUE.     but I would expect TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see, the equality operator works fine if set up for a RefClass. But the %in% operator doesn't. It just returns TRUE for all elements. Why is that? I know the operator is based on the match function, but what type of comparison is used insight? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help :

```
`%in2%` <- function(e1,e2) {
  unname(sapply(e1, function(x) any(sapply(e2, `==`, x))))
}

A2 %in2% A1
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
A1 %in2% A2
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's more or less the same work around I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

They all return as `TRUE` because `match()` coerces lists with `as.character()`.

The result is

```
as.character(A1)
# [1] "new(\"A\", .xData = <environment>)" 
#     "new(\"A\", .xData = <environment>)" "new(\"A\", .xData = <environment>)"
# [4] "new(\"A\", .xData = <environment>)"
```

Below is solution to get the result you're looking for, but given this is a dummy example, it probably won't scale the way you want.

```
A <- setRefClass("A", fields = list(a = "character"))

A$methods(
  equal = function(obj){
    a == obj$a
  }
)

setMethod("==",signature = c("A","A"), function(e1,e2){e1$equal(e2)})

a1 <- A(a="xxx")
a2 <- A(a="yyy")
a3 <- A(a="xxx")

a1 == a2 # FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
a1 == a3 # TRUE
#> [1] TRUE

A1 <- sapply(c("a","b","c","d"),function(x)A(a=x))
A2 <- sapply(c("c","d","e"),function(x)A(a=x))

A1 
#> $a
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $b
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $c
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $d
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "d"
A2   
#> $c
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $d
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $e
#> Reference class object of class "A"
#> Field "a":
#> [1] "e"
class(A1) <- "listof_A"
class(A2) <- "listof_A"
as.list.listof_A<- function(x, ...) {
  # change the function applied to return a regular
  # list or vector representation you are happy with for
  # the class.
  lapply(seq_along(x), function(y) {x[[y]]$field("a")})
}
as.list(A1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "d"

as.list(A2) %in% as.list(A1)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
as.list(A1) %in% as.list(A2)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I originally defined an `as.character()` method for A, in the hopes of `match()` would use it as mentioned in the documentation, but it didn't work out as hoped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the approach. However as you already mentioned by yourself it's not scaling well for complex objects...